# Solr Index Strategy for Q&A Websites

Tags: solr, indexing

I m pretty new with Solr and I would like to use it for the search on a Q&A website (Quora like) I m building.

Here is how Questions and Anwsers are :
Question
 - Title
 - Description
 - Tags (social tags)
 - Score (score comes from user up/down vote the question)

Answers
 - Description
 - Tags
 - Score (score comes from user up/down vote the answer)

Of course you can have as many answer to a question as you want.

There will be three type of documents that need to be index : questions, articles, ...

What would be the best strategy in terms of index to make the Questions and Answers searchable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler), you can have an `<entity>` for the question and then specify a sub-entities for the answers. For example:

```
<document name="questions">
  <entity name="question" query="select id, question from questions">
    <field column="id" name="id" />
    <field column="question" name="question" />

    <entity name="answer" 
        query="select question_id, answer from answers"
        cacheKey="question_id"
        cacheLookup="question.id" 
        processor="CachedSqlEntityProcessor">
      <field name="answer" column="answer" />
    </entity>

  </entity>
</document>
```

Note that this example uses [CachedSqlEntityProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#CachedSqlEntityProcessor) to avoid hitting the database unnecessarily.